# For markov transition matrix and the initial state, calculate probability to reach certain other state in k or less steps

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

So there is a vector `n` giving the initial state and a Markov transition probability matrix `M`. I know I can calculate the probability to reach state `s` in `k` steps with just `n * M**k`.

But what I want is to calculate the probability that I reach the state `s` in `k` steps or less. Is there any simpler method (e.g. using some tweaked matrix multiplication) than to:

1. calculate probability `p` that we reach the state `s` in 1 one step
2. assume we didn't reach it and therefore use `1-p` to multiply the probability that we reach the state `s` in two steps to get probability `p2` and so on up to `k` steps.

Is this approach actually valid?

Now the main question, supposing I need to calculate this probability for all combinations of starting states and final states (i.e. `<number of states> ** 2`), is there then something more simple? An operation that could be done purely on the matrix `M`? So that in the end, I can just multiply the final matrix (generated for `k<=` steps) with the input vector `n` to get the result for one starting state in combination with all the other states by just one multiplication. Is something like that possible?

---

I tried the sum approach suggested by Gregory for `k=2` with numpy and python, doesn't seem to work as the result are not valid probabilites:

```
>>> m
array([[0.25, 0.75],
       [0.45, 0.55]])
>>> r = np.linalg.matrix_power(m, 0) + np.linalg.matrix_power(m, 1) + np.linalg.matrix_power(m, 2)
>>> r
array([[1.65, 1.35],
       [0.81, 2.19]])
>>> np.array([1,0]) @ r
array([1.65, 1.35])
```

Comment: If all the probability information is in the matrix $M$ and $M^k$ tells you the probability of getting to start $s$ in $k$ steps. then why not sum it up?
$$ \sum_{j=0}^k M^j = (I-M)^{-1}(I - M^{k+1}) $$

Comment: You need to change a bit the matrix by making it move from state s to a new absorbing state a whenever s is reached

Comment: (reposted after further edit) Hello @Gregory, I replied above. I am probably doing something wrong in the computation. Can you take a look? I didn't manage to make the suggested equivalent expression for the sum work as there was a problem with the matrix inversion operation.